# Visual Studio 2022 17.4.3 .NET MAUI Android emulation won't work

Tags: android, .net, visual-studio-2022, maui

I am trying to get my first Hello World going in Android emulator in VS 2022 with .NET MAUI:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?view=net-maui-6.0&tabs=vswin&pivots=devices-android
And it is just not happening.
 I started in VS 17.4.0 and Android Oreo that came with it and slowly got up to VS 17.4.3 and Android pixel_5_-_api_31
Here is the VS Output when I run the demo in that Android emulator:

```
    Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: MauiApp2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Starting emulator pixel_5_-_api_31 ...
Couldn't find emulator pixel_5_-_api_31. Resetting...
1>C:\Users\iliab\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\MauiApp2.csproj : warning NU1803: You are running the 'restore' operation with an 'HTTP' source, 'http://nuget.grapecity.com/nuget'. Non-HTTPS access will be removed in a future version. Consider migrating to an 'HTTPS' source.
1>Skipping analyzers to speed up the build. You can execute 'Build' or 'Rebuild' command to run analyzers.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -netfast -accel on -avd pixel_5_-_api_31 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_5_-_api_31
1>MauiApp2 -> C:\Users\iliab\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\bin\Debug\net6.0-android\MauiApp2.dll
1>C:\Users\iliab\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\MauiApp2.csproj : warning NU1803: You are running the 'restore' operation with an 'HTTP' source, 'http://nuget.grapecity.com/nuget'. Non-HTTPS access will be removed in a future version. Consider migrating to an 'HTTPS' source.
1>C:\Users\iliab\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\MauiApp2.csproj : warning NU1803: You are running the 'restore' operation with an 'HTTP' source, 'http://nuget.grapecity.com/nuget'. Non-HTTPS access will be removed in a future version. Consider migrating to an 'HTTPS' source.
1>C:\Users\iliab\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\MauiApp2.csproj : warning NU1803: You are running the 'restore' operation with an 'HTTP' source, 'http://nuget.grapecity.com/nuget'. Non-HTTPS access will be removed in a future version. Consider migrating to an 'HTTPS' source.
1>C:\Users\iliab\source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\MauiApp2.csproj : warning NU1803: You are running the 'restore' operation with an 'HTTP' source, 'http://nuget.grapecity.com/nuget'. Non-HTTPS access will be removed in a future version. Consider migrating to an 'HTTPS' source.
1>Done building project "MauiApp2.csproj".
Emulator pixel_5_-_api_31 cannot be started.
1>Done building project "MauiApp2.csproj".
2>------ Deploy started: Project: MauiApp2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Starting deployment to pixel_5_-_api_31 ...
2>Starting emulator pixel_5_-_api_31 ...
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -netfast -accel on -avd pixel_5_-_api_31 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_5_-_api_31
2>Emulator pixel_5_-_api_31 cannot be started.
2>Deploy failed
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:10.323 ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:10.323 ==========
```

Here is the output of running that emulator in command line:

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE" -netfast -accel on -avd pixel_5_-_api_31 -prop monodroid.avdname=pixel_5_-_api_31
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)
WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator.
WARNING | unexpected '-prop' value ('monodroid.avdname=pixel_5_-_api_31'), only 'qemu.*' properties are supported
INFO    | added library vulkan-1.dll
INFO    | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz
INFO    | Sending adb public key [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 @unknown]
INFO    | Rootcanal has  been activated.
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\iliab\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_22892.ini
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'
INFO    | Deleting snapshot default_boot
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
INFO    | Shutting down gRPC endpoint
INFO    | Shutting down gRPC endpoint
INFO    | Closing down rootcanal.
```

These are various checkboxes in Android SDK Manager currently on:

[image]
[image]
[image]

With HAXM Accelerator unchecked, it just hangs (left it overnight). In both cases it flashes the Emulator window for a second and then closes it.

Comment: Did you try to start the emulator by clicking the start button? You can also try to delete this `Emulator pixel_5_-_api_31` and create a new one. In addition, you can deploy it to the physical device.

Comment: I did try clicking start button :) I tried deleting emulator and installing various other ones in Devices manager. Unchecking undroid emulator checkbox in SDK manager, does not for some reason result in a different version coming with a different device it's always the same one. I tried also installing an emulator from Intell site but that did not result in getting it visible in VS (or anywhere else). Yes I can deploy it on physical device but my questionis about the emulator not physical device :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a hunch that the problem was related to some hardware shortage on my real Windows machine that Android was trying to take over resources from - memory disk space, camera, sound etc.
So I picked the emulator that was the most basic available and then disabled or limited its hardware as much as I could. Disabled FastBoot as well to stop it from saving snapshot and using disk space

[image]

I also tried to clear up as much disk as I could. Each time I tried something the available disk space kept decreasing even if I uninstalled it later.
 For example when you add and then remove an Android device the removed device leaves behind a directory in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images** which can be very large.
I then changed the minimum target Android Framework in Android target on the project to match the emulator I picked. Also note .Net 6 as target run time. .Net 7 is still a problem for me even for a Windows target.
[image]

Of course make sure your SDK manager has the check marks checked for matching API level of the device you chose. 
[image]
[image]
And finally it worked.